# How to check if a point intersects a polygon

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, spatial, shapefile

I am struggling to understand how to work with spatial data. I have uploaded a shape file to SQL Server using shape2sql. The coordinates in the shape file is apparently of geometry type.

In my database table I now have a polygon

```
'POLYGON ((1327562.625 6625818.5, 1327532.125 6625818.5, 1327506.625 6625817, 1327477.5 6625813, 1327452.125 6625808, 1327428 6625798.5, 1327392.5 6625779.5, 1327359.625 6625762.5, 1327331.75 6625748.5, 1327295 6625730.5, 1327260.375 6625693, 1327214 6625694.5, 1327196.75 6625674.5, 1327157 6625672.5, 1327124 6625659.5, 1327096.125 6625649, 1327064.5 6625637.5, 1327034 6625625.5, 1326999.875 6625609, 1326970.75 6625587, 1326950.625 6625570.5, 1326923.875 6625569, 1326914 6625538.5, 1326910.5 6625499, 1326908.125 6625470, 1326907.125 6625443, 1326883.875 6625379, 1326838.75 6625350.5, 1326780.375 6625106, 1326766.75 6625049, 1326759.5 6625019, 1326748 6624971, 1326734.75 6624915, 1326723.625 6624874.5, 1326721.375 6624839, 1326719.125 6624807, 1326719.375 6624766.5, 1326719.625 6624738.5, 1326719.875 6624709.5, 1326722.75 6624679, 1326723 6624636, 1326723.25 6624603, 1326721 6624572.5, 1326713.625 6624539.5, 1326702.5 6624510, 1326687.5 6624474.5, 1326673.75 6624440, 1326660.125 6624408, 1326646.375 6624375, 1326631.375 6624346, 1326616.375 6624316.5, 1326601.25 6624293.5, 1326586.125 6624273, 1326559.75 6624238.5, 1326544.625 6624217, 1326520.875 6624180, 1326493.375 6624122.5, 1326473.25 6624092, 1326448.125 6624055, 1326424.25 6624023, 1326400.375 6623988.5, 1326380.25 6623953, 1326365.375 6623920, 1326352.875 6623885.5, 1326340.5 6623852.5, 1326325.5 6623809, 1326320.625 6623784, 1326320.875 6623757, 1326321.125 6623723, 1326322.625 6623693.5, 1326325.375 6623667, 1326330.75 6623635.5, 1326352.625 6623604, 1326366.75 6623582.5, 1326401.75 6623537, 1326439.75 6623520.5, 1326482 6623492, 1326515.125 6623471.5, 1326548.375 6623453, 1326573.875 6623439, 1326599.5 6623426.5, 1326632.625 6623413, 1326664.5 6623403, 1326695.125 6623393, 1326730.75 6623378, 1326772.875 6623362, 1326809.875 6623349.5, 1326842.875 6623347.5, 1326873.5 6623343.5, 1326899.125 6623317, 1326935 6623280.5, 1326959.375 6623255.5, 1326971 6623230, 1326977.625 6623197, 1326983 6623170.5, 1326993.25 6623146.5, 1326994.75 6623120, 1326995.125 6623084.5, 1326996.625 6623059, 1327001.875 6623032.5, 1327019.875 6623003.5, 1327044.375 6622970.5, 1327067.5 6622931.5, 1327088.125 6622906, 1327103.5 6622883.5, 1327125.375 6622846.5, 1327142.25 6622806.5, 1327151.375 6622778.5, 1327164.375 6622747, 1327178.625 6622720, 1327198 6622678.5, 1327205.875 6622653, 1327213.625 6622626.5, 1327230.625 6622583.5, 1327246.125 6622552, 1327261.625 6622518, 1327275.875 6622483.5, 1327288.75 6622457, 1327301.75 6622425.5, 1327312.125 6622402.5, 1327323.75 6622378.5, 1327336.75 6622353.5, 1327348.375 6622330.5, 1327367.625 6622295, 1327388.375 6622258.5, 1327414 6622223, 1327432 6622203, 1327448.75 6622180.5, 1327469.25 6622151, 1327492.5 6622118.5, 1327516.875 6622088, 1327545.125 6622056.5, 1327570.75 6622021.5, 1327596.5 6621989.5, 1327619.625 6621958, 1327644.125 6621921.5, 1327666 6621890, 1327693 6621846, 1327712.375 6621814, 1327731.625 6621780, 1327756.125 6621741, 1327778 6621705.5, 1327801.25 6621664, 1327816.75 6621637.5, 1327840 6621598, 1327860.5 6621569, 1327882.375 6621544, 1327908 6621523.5, 1327936.125 6621503.5, 1327968 6621486, 1327998.75 6621463.5, 1328031.875 6621441, 1328063.875 6621424.5, 1328098.375 6621407, 1328135.375 6621391, 1328167.25 6621376, 1328196.625 6621359.5, 1328222.125 6621343.5, 1328246.375 6621328, 1328270.625 6621318.5, 1328301.25 6621309.5, 1328340.75 6621305, 1328368.75 6621298.5, 1328407 6621289, 1328449 6621279, 1328474.375 6621275.5, 1328501.125 6621275.5, 1328527.875 6621276, 1328557.125 6621274.5, 1328594 6621273.5, 1328633.375 6621275.5, 1328671.5 6621275.5, 1328707.125 6621276, 1328741.375 6621282.5, 1328787 6621293, 1328818.75 6621306, 1328846.5 6621324, 1328884.5 6621349.5, 1328909.75 6621360, 1328940.25 6621369, 1328971.875 6621379.5, 1329001.125 6621388.5, 1329032.75 6621399, 1329058.125 6621409, 1329083.5 6621418, 1329108.75 6621430, 1329132.875 6621441.5, 1329158.125 6621455.5, 1329182.25 6621468.5, 1329205 6621481.5, 1329246.75 6621503, 1329284.75 6621517.5, 1329317.75 6621528, 1329370 6621522, 1329403 6621514.5, 1329428.5 6621507, 1329478 6621516.5, 1329528.875 6621523, 1329574.5 6621535, 1329599.875 6621541.5, 1329630.375 6621549.5, 1329663.375 6621553.5, 1329698.875 6621560, 1329730.5 6621580.5, 1329759.625 6621599.5, 1329787.5 6621612.5, 1329878.625 6621500.5, 1330416 6621701, 1330484.375 6621583.5, 1331722.625 6622039.5, 1331783.125 6622415.5, 1331786.75 6622441, 1331835 6622613, 1331837.25 6622639.5, 1331806 6622727, 1331743.375 6622771, 1331705 6622797, 1331684.5 6622818.5, 1331664 6622844, 1331647.25 6622865.5, 1331630.5 6622889.5, 1331607.375 6622922, 1331591.875 6622953.5, 1331580.125 6622991.5, 1331330.25 6624007.5, 1331168.875 6624933, 1330912.625 6624902, 1330720.875 6624917.5, 1330851.25 6625309, 1330245 6625523.5, 1330053.25 6625048, 1328694.875 6625608, 1328025.5 6625648.5, 1327997.375 6625650, 1327940.625 6625662.5, 1327897 6625672, 1327834 6625686.5, 1327810 6625718, 1327757.875 6625738.5, 1327730.75 6625772, 1327697.625 6625786.5, 1327664.375 6625801.5, 1327624.875 6625811.5, 1327593.125 6625816.5, 1327562.625 6625818.5))
```

I then define a point from Google maps that I atleast thinks is in the area:

```
geometry::STPointFromText('POINT(59.528355 13.321609)',4326);
```

Finally I try to check if the point is in the are using STIntersects but that always returns false.

I can see that the format of the coordinates between the polygon and the point seems to differ. Is that the problem and if it is, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your polygon haas one coordinate system and your point is in another. The 4326 is the epsg code for lat-long coordinates and your polygon could be anything, but is probably some utm zone.

Find out the epsg code of your polygon data and convert to epsg 4326 using the coordinate transformation function of your db...

Comment: Thanks! The polygon was in RT90 format and when I transformed it to WGS84 it worked.